# はく and きる or just きる?

Tags: word-choice

Textbook says はく is for stuff you wear below your waist (ジーンズをはいている) and きる for stuff you wear above your waist (T-シャツをきています). But checking for 着る on [www.tangorin.com](http://www.tangorin.com) I find 着る defined as **to wear (in modern Japanese, from the shoulders down); to put on**. Does this mean I can just discard はく and use きる for everything shoulders down?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference has to do with *how the clothing is put on*.

[着]{き}る is for clothing that's *hung from your shoulders*, such as a shirt or jacket. It's also used for whole-body outfits, or any combination of clothes that includes something worn this way (eg Tシャツとジーンズを着る, even though only Tシャツ is valid with 着る).

[履]{は}く is for clothing that's *pulled up from below*, such as pants or shoes. (Don't mix this up with 吐く, which is a totally different verb.)

[被]{かぶ}る is for clothing that's *placed on top of your head*, such as a hat.

つける is for small accessories like rings and earrings, that are more *attached* than placed or hung.

Sometimes more than one is valid - masks, for example, seem to fall inbetween 被る and つける, and so you can use either one.

(thanks to Darius Jahandarie for some extra info)

Comment: And かける (usually with no kanji) for glasses!

Comment: Great way of breaking it out. Some thoughts: (1) 「仮面をつける」 and 「仮面をかぶる」 both work. (2) full outfits seem to use 「〜を着る」: 「Tシャツとジーンズを着る」「水着を着る」「熊のコスチュームを着る」

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks for the additions, updating to include!

Comment: Some things are also はめるed, such as wristwatches.

Answer (score 0):

着る is for part on the upper body(but not everything, so is write from shoulder down, like  put the cap 帽子{ぼうし}を被る{かぶる} put glasses メガネをかける) and for one piece like kimono 着物{きもの} 水着{みずぎ} ecc. ecc.

はく is from the ankle to the tip of the toe (lower body included shoes).