# How can I express "wearing multiple clothings" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunctions

Linked [はく and きる or just きる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19637/%e3%81%af%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8b-or-just-%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8b)

ぼうしをかぶるじょせい。
ワンピスをきるじょせい。

How can I express in Japanese the combinations of above sentences, eg:

1. "woman that  is wearing hat and onepiece" or,
2. "woman that is wearing onepiece and hat" or,
3. "woman wearing a hat and wearing a onepiece" or,
4. "woman wearing a onepiece and wearing a hat"

How is which verb to use is decided?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4965/9831

Answer (score 3):

1. ぼうしをかぶり、ワンピースをきた（きている）じょせい
2. ワンピースとぼうしをみにつけた（つけている）じょせい
3. ぼうしとワンピースをみにつけた（つけている）じょせい
4. ワンピースをき、ぼうしをかぶった（かぶっている）じょせい

帽子{ぼうし}を被{かぶ}る、ワンピースを着{き}る、ズボン／スカートを穿{は}く、ソックス／靴下{くつした}／靴{くつ}を履{は}く。アクセサリーを着{つ}ける（付{つ}ける）

身{み}に着{つ}ける is a verb phrase that can be applied to anything. But it sounds formal.

I'm not good at English. This is my first post. I hope this post helps.

Comment: related: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B https://jisho.org/search/%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%AB%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B